# The probability of two balls going into the same bin

Tags: balls-in-bins

Suppose I have *n* bins and *n* balls with label on them. What would be the probability that I throw the *i* th ball into the same bin as the *j* th ball? Is it just 1/*n* because there is a probability of 1/*n* for the *i* th ball to fall into the same bin as wherever the *j* th is.

Comment: yes, assuming that the probability for each bin is 1/n